# For loop to write webscraped data to excel does not move past first link

Tags: python-3.x

I'm scraping the urls in a list called 'cos' and writing the data to an excel file. Code works well for the first link and then script stops running. Any thoughts?
Thank you!

```
newb= xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = newb.add_sheet("Sheet 1")
for url in cos:
    hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,"lxml")
    links = []
    row_num +=1
    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
        links=list(set(links)) #gets rid of duplicate links
    maintext=[]
    col_num=1
    for url in links:
        if ('about' or 'frequently' or 'faq') in url:
            hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
            req1 = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
            html = urllib.request.urlopen(req1)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml") 
            for script in soup(["script", "style"]): # kill all script and style elements
                script.extract()    # rip it out
            text = soup.get_text() # get text
            # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
            lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
            # break multi-headlines into a line each
            chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
            # drop blank lines
            text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
            add = url + text
            sheet1.write(row_num,col_num,add)
            col_num += 1
            print(col_num)
            # newb.save("webscrap.xls")
        else:
            pass

newb.save("webscrap.xls")
```